# Update Page without reload AJAX/PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm having some troble with AJAX call to update a page after insert the info in the DB.

I update the form, but i need to update the form after the update.

Need some help, i'm not so good whit javascript.

Thks!

```
<script>
 function chk()
  {
var nome=document.getElementById('nome').value;
var dataString= 'nome='+ nome;
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url: default,
    data:dataString,
    cache:false
    //success: function(html){
      //  $('#msg').html(html);
    //}
 });
return false;
 }
 </script>
```

All the code i use, it's not final and not uptimized, its a form, update the field, and i want to update with the changes, without make a page refresh

```
<div class="col-md-12 personal-info">


            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Nome:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nome" name="nome" value="<?php echo name($resultado); ?>">
                    <!--<input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php $nome; ?>">-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Apelido:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo apelido($chamada); ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Morada:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo morada(); ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Código Postal:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo codigopostal(); ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Localidade:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo localidade(); ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Email:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo email(); ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Username:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $current_user->user_login ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" value="11111122333">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm password:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" value="11111122333">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes" onclick="return chk()">
                    <!--<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes">-->
                    <span></span>
                    <input type="reset" name="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <hr>

<!--teste final-->

<?php
global $wpdb;
global $seconddb;
global $current_user;

if ($_POST['submit']){
    $new = $_POST['nome'];

    $query = $seconddb->query("UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}sgc_socios SET nome='$new' WHERE email = '{$current_user->user_email}' ");

}


 ?>    

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

   <script>
   function chk()
   {
   var nome=document.getElementById('nome').value;
   var dataString= 'nome='+ nome;
   $.ajax({
      type:"post",
      url: default,
      data:dataString,
    cache:false
    //success: function(html){
      //  $('#msg').html(html);
    //}
});
return false;
}
</script>
```

Thks for the help!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the ajax call?

Comment: Show the changins i made, after press the submit button, whitout press F5 to update the page.

Update the page, without reload the page.

Thks!

Comment: `url: default,`, `default` is the reserved keyword, you can not use that

Comment: @RakeshJakhar, ok, thks! I changed it for the right URL.